# Стало больше на две собаки или на двух собак?

Tags: грамматика, числительные

Как правильно: стало больше на две собаки или на двух собак?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**Допускаются оба варианта** для сущ. ж. рода, обозначающих живых существ, но не людей (примечание из Грамматики-80): **стало больше на двух собак/на две собаки.**

**Пояснение для основной формы "на двух собак"**

А как с остальным числом собак? Стало больше на одну собаку, на трех собак, на пять собак.

Таким образом, мы видим что **выбор формы падежа зависит от числительного,** а именно: категорию одушевленности выражают только числительные **два, три, четыре** (и собирательные числительные).

Числительное *один* согласуется с существительным (В.п.), числительное пять не имеет категории одушевленности (В.п.)

Что касается собирательных числительных, то они по правилу могут относиться  к невзрослым животным: двое щенят, на двоих щенят.

Comment: @ Arina, а нельзя сказать: больше на две собаки?

Comment: Вот думаю. Может, при наличии предлога правила не такие строгие. Примеры из Нацкорпуса: (1)... и обращала его внимание на двух собак, по-домашнему ищущих крошек под узким, бедно убранным столом. [В. В. Набоков.  (1929-1930)] ..., остатков не хватило бы и на двух собак! [Д. С. Мережковский.  (1901)]  (2) Выменял его у Чепракова на две собаки. [А. П. Чехов.  (1890-1900)]

Comment: Нет, предлог здесь ни при чём, нашла в Грамматике 80. При сочетании с сущ. ж. рода, обозначающих живых существ, но не людей, возможен В.п.: Поймал трех птичек и три птички. "На них он выменял борзые три собаки".

Comment: Пример из Нацкорпуса: Конвой наш был увеличен еще **на два** солдата. [С. И. Гусев-Оренбургский. Багровая книга. Погромы 1919-20 гг. на Украине (1922)]. Как эти объяснить?

Comment: Мне кажется, что В.п. в таких выражениях связан с постановкой вопроса: На сколько собак стало больше, на сколько солдат увеличен конвой?  Дело в том, что неопределенные числительные выражают одушевленность/неодушевленность непоследовательно, например: я знаю несколько/нескольких человек.  Поэтому В.п. сохраняется в ответах,  и на слух нормально воспринимаются оба варианта.

Answer (score 0):

Третий ещё вариант возможен: двоих! )))

Нашла такое правило (по-моему, самое то):

> С одушевленными существительными, как правило, употребляется
> собирательное числительное двое, которое имеет все формы косвенных
> падежей. С неодушевленными существительными собирательное числительное
> образует только именительный и винительный падежи, в остальных его
> заменяет количественное числительное два.

[**источник**](http://thedifference.ru/kak-pishetsya-pravilno-dvux-ili-dvoix/)

Ввиду некоторой одушевлённости собачек, пишем:

***стало больше на двух собак.***

Comment: Безупречен только четвёртый вариант: __стало двумя собаками больше__ :)

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: Третий ещё вариант возможен: **двоих!** ))) Нашла такое правило..._ === И как это _правило_ связано с последней строкой Вашего ответа ("стало больше на **двух** собак")?

Comment: Да, Слава, спасибо. Писала на больную голову.